# Yii url manager for modules

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15, and am trying to shorted my url's for a module i have. Right now the url are like this

```
url/alerts/alerts/admin
url/alerts/alerts/create
```

i'd like to change it to

```
url/alerts/admin
url/alerts/create
```

I have this, but doesn't work

```
'<action:(create|admin)>' => 'alerts/<action>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
'alerts/<action:(create|admin)>' => 'alerts/alerts/<action>',
```